# How to use bcp utility in a CLR procedure as a process

Tags: sql-server, sql-clr

I made an CLR Stored Procedure and I want to call bcp utility as a process in it.
My project looks like :

```
[SqlProcedure]
public static int CmdShellBridgeBCP(string arguments)
{
       return processCMD("bcp.exe", arguments);
}

private static int processCMD(string fileName, string arguments)
{
     try
     {
           Process proc = new Process();
           proc.StartInfo.FileName = fileName;
           proc.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
           proc.Start();
           proc.WaitForExit();
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
           return 1;
     }
     return 0;
}
```

And the stored procedure where I try to use this looks like :

```sql
set     @execcommand = @CSSdbname+'.BankCardtrxGPEtemp in '+@importdir + @Kfilename +' -c -S '+@CSSserver+' -r \n -T -C 1250 -e '+@importdir+'bcp.error -m 1000 >NUL'

exec    @result = dbo.CmdShellBridgeBCP @execcommand
```

Now the result is that nothing was imported in my BankCardtrxGPEtemp  table.
I have no errors, the return value is 0, not 1.

If I use

```sql
exec    @result = master..xp_cmdshell @execcommand, NO_OUTPUT
```

it works ok.
But I want not to use `xp_cmdshell`.

What is wrong with my code ?

Assembly has `UNSAFE` permission, because I have to use external shared folders to access files (txt, cvs, etc ...)

Comment: It should be noted that this question has been cross-posted on SQL Server Central: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1722932-386-1.aspx . Also, the `UNSAFE` permission was needed in order to use the `Process` class. Accessing the file system only required `EXTERNAL_ACCESS`.

Comment: Have you tried this without the ">NUL"?

Comment: I will try to explain exactly what I want with my project. Tiil now we use xp_cmdshell for various command line calls from sql. (bcp, mkdir, net use, del, md, rd and other). We use them especially on remote share folders. Now, I want to use instead of xp_cmdshell an CLR project where I want to create stored procedures for every command :